# Cannot find app scripts ionic

Tags: angular, cordova, plugins, ionic3, upgrade

i'm using ionic 3 & i have a problem when installing a new cordova plugin , ionic serve says "Cannot find app/scripts"
this trouble appears after upgrading from ionic 3.7 to 3.8.
the app/scripts exist in my package.json but not on my node_modules
any ideas ?

Answer (score 0):

Just **delete** `node_modules` folder and then run `npm i`

I highly recommend upgrading your app to [**Ionic 3.9.2**](https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic/releases)

Comment: when running npi i i've this error : npm i
npm WARN deprecated object-keys@0.2.0: Please update to the latest object-keys
npm ERR! Unexpected end of input at 1:32314
npm ERR! ":"^2.2.1","mocha-lcov-reporter":"^0.0.2"},"bin":{"node-sass":"bin/no
npm ERR!                                                                      ^

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\CHENNA\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2017-12-12T08_09_23_216Z-debug.log

Answer (score 0):

Just run this command for ionic 3

```
npm install -g @ionic/app-scripts@latest --save-dev
```